# How to remove black part from the image?

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, image-stitching

I have stitched two images together using OpenCV functions and C++. Now I am facing a problem that the final image contains a large black part.

The final image should be a rectangle containing the effective part. 
My image is the following:

[image]

How can I remove the black section?

Comment: You could probably use cvFindContours to get the extents of your image content and then crop to that...

Comment: while adding images in question, output the result using `imwrite` and add it. It is better than adding screenshot, because those who answer your question need to remove unwanted regions from the image.

Comment: Your workspace is kind of tidy.

Comment: How exactly would you like to remove the black part? Is it okay if the upper-left corner of the new image is the same as it is currently, and the lower-right corner is at the lowest part of the stitched image? Would you like to cut it so it contains minimal amount of black parts while still containing all the image-parts, or vice-versa, so it cuts out minimal amount of image part while removing all the black parts? Elaborate please :)

Comment: I've implemented https://github.com/OpenStitching/lir exactly for this purpose. It is used e.g. in https://github.com/OpenStitching/stitching

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`mevatron`'s answer is one way where amount of black region is minimised while retaining full image.

Another option is removing complete black region where you also loose some part of image, but result will be a neat looking rectangular image. Below is the Python code.

Here, you find three main corners of the image as below:

[image]

I have marked those values. `(1,x2), (x1,1), (x3,y3)`. It is based on the assumption that your image starts from (1,1).

**Code :**

First steps are same as `mevatron`'s. Blur the image to remove noise, threshold the image, then find contours.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('office.jpg')
img = cv2.resize(img,(800,400))

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.medianBlur(gray,3)

ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,1,255,0)
contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

Now find the biggest contour which is your image. It is to avoid noise in case if any (Most probably there won't be any). Or you can use `mevatron`'s method.

```
max_area = -1
best_cnt = None

for cnt in contours:
    
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    if area > max_area:
        max_area = area
        best_cnt = cnt
```

Now approximate the contour to remove unnecessary points in contour values found, but it preserve all corner values.

```
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(best_cnt,0.01*cv2.arcLength(best_cnt,True),True)
```

Now we find the corners.

First, we find (x3,y3). It is farthest point. So `x3*y3` will be very large. So we find products of all pair of points and select the pair with maximum product.

```
far = approx[np.product(approx,2).argmax()][0]
```

Next (1,x2). It is the point where first element is one,then second element is maximum.

```
ymax = approx[approx[:,:,0]==1].max()
```

Next (x1,1). It is the point where second element is 1, then first element is maximum.

```
xmax = approx[approx[:,:,1]==1].max()
```

Now we find the `minimum values in (far.x,xmax) and (far.y, ymax)`

```
x = min(far[0],xmax)
y = min(far[1],ymax)
```

If you draw a rectangle with (1,1) and (x,y), you get result as below:

[image]

So you crop the image to correct rectangular area.

```
img2 = img[:y,:x].copy()
```

Below is the result:

[image]

`See, the problem is that you lose some parts of the stitched image.`

Comment: :Since i am more acquainted with C++ and tried to convert the code(in python) to C++ but was not able to succeed much.If you could please share the same code in C++ language,i would be highly thankful.

Comment: i am sorry, i am not good in c++. But if you tell me if you have any doubt about any step in my method, i can explain in much more simpler way.

Comment: :I have done all the steps till approxpolyDP, But I dont know how to calculate the product of coordinate points in C and I think you have also used pseudo code.Can you tell me how can I calculate the product of coordinate points in C or give me any link where somebody have used your type of method in C.For reference my image after applying approxpoly() method is [http://i.imgur.com/Qfoyt.jpg?1] .Hope you also got the same output image after applying approxpolyDp().

Comment: My code is a working code in opencv python api. Actually i get a list of 4 coordinates like `approx = [[a,b],[c,d],[e,f],[g,h],[i,j]]`. Now i take each set and multiply their values and store it in another array. Like, `for i in approx: k[0]=i[0]*i[1]`. Now take the argument of maximum value in resulting array. This i have done in a single step with help of numpy, a python library : `far = approx[np.product(approx,2).argmax()][0]`

Comment: okay.But,I think in C ,we can not take coordinates like this.Can you tell me some other method .I have seen in SO that Hough transform is use to get lines,but I think that will increase the complexity unnecessarily.Do you know any other method?

Comment: I think a cvSeq object is returned as function of approxpolyDP function. You can extract the values from cvSeq using `h_next,h_prev` attributes. You can find them in documentation : http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?        highlight=cvseq#cvseq                               ,Also try `cvgetseqelem` function. http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvseq#getseqelem

Comment: Sir, h_next and h_prev are used to point the next contours in the contour tree/list .And In my image I have just one Contour.Anyways Thanks for your help,your reply really helped me a lot.Thank you

Comment: @AbidRahmanK Have you worked in Matlab? I am having trouble finding fucntions corresponding to `cv2.approxPolyDP()` and `cv2.arcLength()`. Your approach is exactly what I need but getting stuck at the functions. Please have a look at my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35170367/how-to-find-black-patch-in-an-image-in-matlab

Comment: Thank you, that works well (@deepak_k - let me know if you need assistance in translating the code to c++) . @Abid Do you think it's good idea to re-stitch this cropped image with the source images in order to restore some of the lost details in the cropping? or are there other approaches?

Answer (score 9):

You can do this with [threshold](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html?cv2.threshold#threshold), [findContours](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#void%20findContours%28InputOutputArray%20image,%20OutputArrayOfArrays%20contours,%20OutputArray%20hierarchy,%20int%20mode,%20int%20method,%20Point%20offset%29), and [boundingRect](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontour#boundingrect).

So, here is a quick script doing this with the python interface.

```
stitched = cv2.imread('stitched.jpg', 0)
(_, mask) = cv2.threshold(stitched, 1.0, 255.0, cv2.THRESH_BINARY);

# findContours destroys input
temp = mask.copy()
(contours, _) = cv2.findContours(temp, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# sort contours by largest first (if there are more than one)
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda contour:len(contour), reverse=True)
roi = cv2.boundingRect(contours[0])

# use the roi to select into the original 'stitched' image
stitched[roi[1]:roi[3], roi[0]:roi[2]]
```

Ends up looking like this:
[image]

**NOTE :** Sorting may not be necessary with raw imagery, but using the compressed image caused some compression artifacts to show up when using a low threshold, so that is why I post-processed with sorting.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use active contours (balloons/snakes) for selecting the black region accurately. A demonstration can be found [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o5gqYY41HJA). Active contours are available in OpenCV, check [cvSnakeImage](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html?highlight=snake#cvSnakeImage).

Comment: Can you show me how to  implement it for removing the black part?

Comment: The links you added are all dead. It's much better to show and explain an implementation so that your answer is timeless.