# How to find black patch in an image in Matlab?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I have an image pair.[image]
[image]

What I require is to report changes b/w them(which I'm able to do).

The program also shows changes where there is the big black patch in Image1. While it is definitely a change, I require such changes(where there is no information(black patch) in one of the images) to be ignored.

For eg, in the given pair, only the hexagon should be shown as a change. Thus, I need to locate the coordinates of either the patch or image sans the patch.
I came across an approach [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632617/how-to-remove-black-part-from-the-image).

How can I achieve this in Matlab? The approach works great, but I am having trouble finding the functions corresponding to the `cv2` functions in Matlab (particularly `cv2.approxpolyDP()` and `cv2.arclength()`.Tried using `regionprops` but to no avail.

Is there any other way too, other than the one in the [linked approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10632617/how-to-remove-black-part-from-the-image?lq=1)

PS:I am new to Matlab.

Comment: You have posted a link to the reference manual. I think it pretty much explains how you can extract the x and y values for each contour of the `ContourMatrix`, so you'd simply have to sum up the distances between each of the (x, y) pairs. BTW: Are you sure that the longest contour will do in your case? Have you plotted the contours that are found over your image?

Comment: Actually what I intend to do is entirely different. I need to report any changes b/w a pair of similar images(read satellite images), with minor differences. I am able to perform that, but in some image pairs,one (only one) of the image has such black patches on the corners. Since that is also a change(for my algorithm), it gets reported, but I don't want such changes to be reported. Thus I'm seeking to isolate that black patch before performing change detection, so that the previously non-black image now gets black in the very same patch(thus algorithm concludes no change in that patch)

Comment: Wasn't paying attention while reading the manual. Got it now.